# Emerging Standards for file transfer and integrity check?

Tags: authentication

What are the emerging standards for file transfers (including online transactions)?  How about for file integrity checks?

Comment: In what context?  The answer may be domain-specific.  The security requirements for file transfer in, say, health care or military systems are pretty different from those for, say, ad campaigns.

Comment: This has been a *solved problem* since sometime in the mid 70's, so there really are not "emerging standards".

Answer (score 2):

There's not much more to it than "use SSL for file transfers, use digital signatures (e.g. PGP) for file authenticity".

The recommended ciphers are AES for a symmetric cipher and RSA for an asymmetric cipher. Any SHA2 family hash should be safe as a hash function.

Answer (score 2):

I can't think of anything "emerging." The algorithms have changed over time, but the principles have been the same for decades:

- Just because any discussion of error checking would be remiss without knowing and understanding this, I'm throwing in the [parity bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_bit). Rarely used in any practical capacity that isn't low-level hardware type stuff such as RAID or bits on a wire.
- Simple accidental bit transmission errors: checksums. See CRC32. Very computationally inexpensive, but not useful against an attack scenario.
- Strong check for correctness: cryptographic checksums. See MD5, SHA1, SHA2. SHA2 is the current vanguard. For some purposes, MD5 and SHA1 are now considered weakened.
- Verifying hash authenticity: cryptographic checksum signed by private keypair. See signing in PGP, OpenSSL, anything referencing RSA, etc.

There are also error-correcting codes that "oversend" information. See the [implementation of Reed-Solomon ECC in QR codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_code#Error_correction)

Answer (score 0):

There is secure messaging standard for real-time electronic exchange of securities transactions called [FIX](http://fixprotocol.org/what-is-fix.shtml). It is used mainly in financial domain.